# How to search for multiple file types?

Tags: mac, finder

My goal is to search for all files with any of the 3 file extensions I specify. I tried various things but to no avail:

1. **Via the advanced search.** Problem: no OR option.

[image]

2. **Search field.** Problem: It's not giving the dropdown for the next kind keyword.

[image]

As a workaround, I tried using 2 different windows to combine the kind options together. Problem: OR doesn't work.

[image]

3. **Metadata**. I wanted to use the MetaData for extension, but there seems to be none available.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A vanilla solution is to hold `option` and click the plus icon (now transformed into `...`) for adding a new rule. This will give a list of options, among which is the `Any` rule.
(You may need to delete the initial rule; the option click method only works on subsequent rules)

Screenshot:
[image: Example 'any' rule]

Answer (score 2):

Download the app **EasyFind** from the Mac App store. It has a different set of search filters that may enable you to find your files. You can specify it to find files with several extensions and tell it to find files with at least one of the words or extensions in your case. EasyFind is free.

Comment: Right now this reads like a marketing text. How exactly can the to be used to solve the problem described in the question? And while you are at it, can you also include a link to make it easier for anybody interested in the application?

Comment: Unfortunately, seems EasyFind didn't get an update since Jul 23 2014 and there's a review saying it doesn't work in El Capitan itself. It won't likely work on higher OS X versions as well. Anyways, Benjamin Gray already provided the absolute answer I was looking for and I have accepted it. Thanks for your input anyways.